# Implementing logic from aspx.cs to aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to make all TextBox controls read only in my .aspx page.  I've written this in my aspx.cs page:

```
private void SetTextBoxReadOnly(Control parent, bool readOnly)
{
  // Get all TextBoxes and set the value of the ReadOnly property.
  foreach (var tb in parent.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
    tb.ReadOnly = readOnly;

  // Recurse through all Controls
  foreach(Control c in parent.Controls)
    SetReadOnly(c, readOnly);
}
```

Obviously I have a ton of TextBoxes in the .aspx page such as this one:

```
                <div class="form-group">
                    <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtTimePointsExplained" CssClass="col-md-2 control-label">Explain why these time points:</asp:Label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtTimePointsExplained" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="8" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox></div>
                </div>
```

Obviously it's not making my textboxes readOnly.  I don't think there is anything wrong with the logic, which leads me to believe it's not being interpreted by the .aspx page.

Comment: Does anything call `SetTextBoxReadOnly`?  What does `SetReadOnly` do?  When you step through this in the debugger, does it actually find the text box controls?

Comment: Nothing is calling the method in the .aspx page.  I don't know how to do that, hence the original question.  I -think- SetReadOnly should be the name of the original method SetTextBoxReadOnly, but I could be mistaken.

Comment: Well, in order for a method to be invoked, you have to *invoke* it.  So you need to actually *call this method* somewhere.    As for `SetReadOnly`, if you don't actually define that method then this won't even compile.  If it is defined, you might want to at least *look at it* before executing it on your page.

Comment: David,

SetReadOnly didn't exist and it didn't comile.  I changed this.

I also figured out how to invoke it on the aspx page

    <script>

        function init()
        {
            <%SetTextBoxReadOnly(parent, readOnly);%>;
        }


    </script>


However, I don't know which arguments to use here.

Comment: If you want to invoke it when the page loads then I imagine you can invoke it in the `Page_Load` event handler.  And if it should find every control on the page, then the top-level one should be the page itself.  Something like: `SetTextBoxReadOnly(this, true);`

Comment: This worked, David.  Thanks.  Could you elaborate a bit more how the this and true parameters work with this code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

There was an error within the original code snippet:

```
private void SetTextBoxReadOnly(Control parent, bool readOnly)
{
  // Get all TextBoxes and set the value of the ReadOnly property.
  foreach (var tb in parent.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
    tb.ReadOnly = readOnly;

  // Recurse through all Controls
  foreach(Control c in parent.Controls)
    SetReadOnly(c, readOnly);
}
```

Here:

```
SetReadOnly(c, readOnly);
```

should be the original method:

```
SetTextBoxReadOnly(c, readOnly);
```

As David said in the comments to invoke this method on the page (at the time it loads)  Call this method in the Page_Load method:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetTextBoxReadOnly(this, true);
    }
```